# What's the best way to store different types in a collection

Tags: scala, types

I have a generic class:

```
class GenericType[T] {
  def func(t: T) = ???
}
```

I need to implement a function that takes a `List[String]` and outputs the corresponding `GenericType[T]`. For example, if a client passes in `List("SomeType1", "SomeType2")`, the function should return `List(GenericType[SomeType1], GenericType[SomeType2])`. Basically, there's a string that maps to a type.

I don't find a good way to represent the return type for such function. `Seq[GenericType[_]]` as the return type can be an option but it requires the client to cast it into corresponding subclasses to invoke `func` as the type info is lost.

Alternatively, a case class can be used but this is not flexible as I need to modify the case class every time a new subclass is added.

```
case class (s1: Option[GenericType[SomeType1]] = None, s2: Option[SomeType2] = None, ...)
```

I'm curious what's a good way to represent the return type?

Comment: How do you expect to know a compile time the type of something that depends on runtime?

Comment: Lists are homogeneous, and using strings to map types is a code smell. The short answer is you can't store multiple types in a collection. You can use a tuple, but it's limited to 22 members and requires storing elements of those types, not the types themselves. This can probably be done with reflection/macros/shapeless/etc, but it's not gonna look pretty.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip If we're doing a choice based on a runtime string then compile-time techniques (macros, implicits, Shapeless) are off the table. Only runtime reflection remains from the listed.

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers. In that case, I guess I should offload this to client to instantiate individual `GenericType[T]` themselves?

Comment: @DmytroMitin Do you mind elaborating a little more on how runtime reflection would help in this case? Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is

```
def stringToGenericType(s: String): GenericType[_] = s match {
  case "SomeType1" => new GenericType[SomeType1]
  case "SomeType2" => new GenericType[SomeType2]
}
```

`GenericType[_]` (or `GenericType[Any]` if you make `GenericType` covariant: `class GenericType[+T]`) would be an honest return type. You can't know at compile time which specific `GenericType[...]` you return based on a runtime string. Anyway you can't avoid casting somewhere because you can't guarantee the type statically. Anyway this kind of programming can't be type-safe.

Since we're doing a choice based on a runtime string, compile-time techniques (macros, implicits, Shapeless) are off the table. (*)

Actually, currently you don't need even runtime reflection. Your class `GenericType[T]` and method `func` in it seem not to do anything at runtime differently depending on type `T`. `GenericType[SomeType1]` and `GenericType[SomeType2]` are just `GenericType[_]` at runtime. So even the following implementation is possible

```
def stringToGenericType(s: String): GenericType[_] = new GenericType[Any]
```

Another situation would be if you created instances of different classes

```
class GenericType1[T]
class GenericType2[T]

import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val runtimeMirror = runtime.currentMirror

def stringToGenericTypeX(s: String): Any = {
  val classSymbol = runtimeMirror.staticClass(s)
  val constructorSymbol = classSymbol.typeSignature.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
  runtimeMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol).reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol).apply()
}
```

or you called different methods

```
class GenericType[T] {
  def func1(t: T) = ???
  def func2(t: T) = ???
}

def callFuncX(methodName: String, t: Any) = {
  val classSymbol = runtimeMirror.classSymbol(classOf[GenericType[_]])
  val methodSymbol = classSymbol.typeSignature.decl(TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  runtimeMirror.reflect(new GenericType[Any]).reflectMethod(methodSymbol).apply(t)
}
```

or something behaved at runtime differently depending on type `T`

```
class GenericType[T: ClassTag] {
  def func(t: T) = println(classTag[T].runtimeClass)
}

import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val toolbox = runtimeMirror.mkToolBox()

def stringToGenericType(s: String): GenericType[_] = {
  toolbox.eval(q"new GenericType[${TypeName(s)}]").asInstanceOf[GenericType[_]]
}
```

---

(*) Well, actually the first pattern matching (as I wrote it) can be automated with a macro

```scala
// in a different subproject
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def stringToGenericType(s: String): GenericType[_] = macro stringToGenericTypeImpl
 
def stringToGenericTypeImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(s: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val cases = List("SomeType1", "SomeType2").map(str =>
    cq"$str => new GenericType[${TypeName(str)}]"
  )
  q"$s match { case ..$cases }"
}
```

```scala
val s = "SomeTime1"
stringToGenericType(s)

     //  scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-debug-lite"
//s match {
//  case "SomeType1" => new GenericType[SomeType1]()
//  case "SomeType2" => new GenericType[SomeType2]()
//}
```